# Does Python keep track of when something has been sorted, internally?

Tags: python, list, sorting

For example, if I call

```
L = [3,4,2,1,5]
L = sorted(L)
```

I get a sorted list. Now, in the future, if I want to perform some other kind of sort on L, does Python automatically know "this list has been sorted before and not modified since, so we can perform some internal optimizations on how we perform this other kind of sort" such as a reverse-sort, etc?

Comment: Not as such, but "Timsort" (the default sort in CPython) looks for ordered subsequences - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: Certainly not with `sorted`, because that redefines the list. But anyways, I doubt Python keeps track of what operations have been done on an object. You could try making a custom type.

Comment: You can find some information on timsort here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/listsort.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't. The sorting algorithm is designed to exploit (partially) sorted inputs, but the list itself doesn't "remember" being sorted in any way.

(This is actually a CPython implementation detail, and future versions/different implementations could cache the fact that a list was just sorted. However, I'm not convinced that could be done without slowing down all operations that modify the list, such as `append`.)

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters pointed out, normal Python lists are inherently ordered and efficiently sortable (thanks, Timsort!), but do not remember or maintain sorting status.

If you want lists that invariably retain their sorted status, you can install the [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) package from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers).

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedList
>>> L = SortedList([3,4,2,1,5])
>>> L
SortedList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> L.add(3.3)
>>> L
SortedList([1, 2, 3, 3.3, 4, 5])
```

Note the normal `append` method becomes `add`, because the item isn't added on the end. It's added wherever appropriate given the sort order. There is also a `SortedListWithKey` type that allows you to set your sort key/order explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this, at least the specific reverse sort question, could be done using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
L = np.array([3,4,2,1,5])
a = np.argsort(L)
b = L[a]
r = L[a[::-1]]

print L
[3 4 2 1 5]

print b
[1 2 3 4 5]

print r
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

That is, here we just do the sort once (to create `a`, the sorting indices), and then we can manipulate `a`, to do other various sorts, like the normal sort `b`, and the reverse sort `r`.  And many others would be similarly easy, like every other element.